# I have acquired an old Minolta Freedom Dual point-and-shoot. What ISO does it shoot at?

Tags: film, point-and-shoot, iso

I have acquired an old Minolta Freedom Dual point-and-shoot camera. It's a straightforward enough device, and pretty automatic: no user set aperture or shutter-speed settings.

But obviously it's choosing some shutter speed. How do I determine what film speed it is targeting? I cannot locate the manual for this camera online with a simple Google search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Minolta Freedom Dual is a film camera, it shoots at whatever ISO film is loaded into it. I have seen a [reference](http://camerapedia.wikia.com/wiki/Minolta_AF-DL) online that ISO 100-400 speed film should be used with this camera. By the time this camera was introduced in 1987 [DX coded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DX_encoding) 35mm film was available. The Freedom Dual may have read the DX coding on film inserted into it.

I would get a roll of ISO 400 and try it in the camera to see what happens.

This [online manual for the later model Freedom Zoom 130](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/368088/Minolta-Freedom-Zoom-130.html#manual) may also be helpful.